# Advice on how to come up with the models my app needs?

Tags: python, django, database, model

I've been thinking about making an online store web app using Django, but I've never made an app without following a tutorial. When following a tutorial, I never really came up with the models my self. How do i know what models my app needs to have so that i can pass it into the database. I already created the front end i just want to know if anyone has an idea or advice so that i can know what models to pass to my database?

Comment: It sounds like you need to know how to create an ERD?

Comment: What is an ERD?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/entity-relationship-diagram-ERD%3famp=1

Answer (score 0):

First if all: This is not that complicated, let me explain:
This day I am building django-project and I started with a very simple model, I makemigrated and migrated it, then I decided that I need another field, and I realized it when I was building the front, so I just remigrated (after manage.py makemigrate...) the model, and Django is very comfortable with such changes!
So my advice is: think about the skeleton of the model and then under construction you can add and modify fields simply.

Second: online web store is not a new idea, you can find a models example in GitHub or similar places to get the idea (for example: https://github.com/justdjango/django-ecommerce/blob/master/core/models.py).

Have a good luck with your project!!